# Correct way of multiplying long values

Tags: c#

I need to figure out which of two fractions is greater than the other one. The fraction structure holds `long` values for numerator and denominator.

The naive approach is as follows:

```
try
{
  checked
  {
    long a = fraction1.Numerator * fraction2.Denominator;
    long b = fraction2.Numerator * fraction1.Denominator;
    return a.CompareTo(b);
  }
}
catch
{
  throw new Exception("CompareTo failed");
}
```

This works fine for a wide range of cases, but by choosing another data type for `a` and `b` the amount of cases where an exception is thrown can be reduced.

What data type would be a good (preferably with no extra libraries to reference) choice? `decimal`? `BigInteger`?

Comment: `decimal` or `BigInteger` would work, but only `decimal` is in the framework with no extra references, of course.

Comment: To stay within the range of `decimal` the biggest number I can "square" is 281,474976,710656 which is a lot smaller than `long.MaxValue` = 9223372,036854,775807

Comment: Whoops - yes, spoke much too soon. Sorry about that. BigInteger or change to a different approach, e.g. finding common factors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by trying performing a decimal multiplication. And only (for performance reasons) if that should fail I make a BigInteger multiplication. Finding common factors is of course done beforehand.

```
try
{
  decimal a = (decimal)fraction1.Numerator * (decimal)fraction2.Denominator;
  decimal b = (decimal)fraction2.Numerator * (decimal)fraction1.Denominator;
  return a.CompareTo(b);
}
catch
{
  BigInteger a = new BigInteger(fraction1.Numerator) * new BigInteger(fraction2.Denominator);
  BigInteger b = new BigInteger(fraction2.Numerator) * new (fraction1.Denominator);
  return a.CompareTo(b);
}
```

Side note: Referencing BigInteger from System.Numerics is acceptable for me in this case, since it comes with .Net 4.

Comment: The checked block is nonsensical in this code. Checked arithmetic only applies to integers.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable hint. I changed my code in my answer.